# Передача параметра из кнопки в ListView во ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, viewmodel

Товарищи, подскажите, как во ViewModel передать параметр кликнутой кнопки? в хамл прописан биндинг на комманду, кнопка во вью модел вызывается, но вот не могу сообразить, как понять, какая кнопка была нажата? У меня несколько кнопок, под каждым товаром с надписью добавить в корзину.

Проверил, работу команд и самой модели ViewModel , работает, если кнопка находится во вне ListView,
А если кнопка внутри ListView почему не работает команда.

Пробовал во View к BindingContext присваивать и к контенту и к переменой ListView, все равно не реагирует.

И соответсвенно когда команда сама заработает, будет видно, передастся ли параметр, по которому был клик

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Код класса View

```
 public ObservableCollection<ItemLPH> ItemsListKategory { get; set; }

    public ItemKategorView (KorzinaViewModel KVM, ItemsLPH LPH, KategoryItem.TypeItem typeItem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = KVM;
        MyListViewKategor.BindingContext = KVM;

        ItemsListKategory = LPH.GetKategoryList(typeItem);
        MyListViewKategor.ItemsSource = ItemsListKategory;

    }
```

Код XAML

```
<ContentPage.Content >
    <StackLayout Padding="5">
        <ListView x:Name="MyListViewKategor"

                  ItemTapped="MyListViewKategor_ItemTapped"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="White" >
                            <StackLayout WidthRequest="160" HeightRequest="120"  Padding="10">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}"   />

                            </StackLayout>                                
                            <StackLayout >
                                <Label  Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                                <Label Text="{Binding CountOneitem}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Rub}" />
                                <Button  Text="В корзину"  Command="{Binding AddDelCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
        <StackLayout> <!-- тест стек находится под листвью -->
            <Label Text="{Binding Message}"/>
            <Button  Text="В корзину"  Command="{Binding AddDelCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Код Страницы ViewModel

```
 public class KorzinaViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public IKorzinaModel korzinaModel;

    //////////////
    ///????
    private ItemLPH _currenItem;//Храним выбраный итем      
    public ItemLPH CurrentItem// Биндинг события клика добавления в корзину
    {
        get { return _currenItem; }
        set
        {
            _currenItem = value;

            if (_currenItem == null) return;

            // заносим в корзину выбранный товар
            korzinaModel.AddItem(_currenItem);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalSumm));// обновляем(перерисовываем) общую сумму покупки

            _currenItem = null;
        }
    }

    public KorzinaViewModel()//конструктор
    {
        this.korzinaModel = new KorzinaModel();
    }


    private string _message = "default text";
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            _message = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Message));
        }            
    }


    public ICommand AddDelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                Message = "клик";
            }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Не должно быть манипуляций с контролами из представления во вьюмодели 2) если таки хотите стрелять себе в ногу, то у кнопки помимо `Command` есть поле `CommandParameter`

Comment: У меня есть список итемов и у каждого итема есть кнопка добавить, вот чтобы понять, какой итем добавить, я и хочу передать ClassId, а подскажите тогда, каким образом можно решить мою проблему? CommandParameter  пробовал использовать, ьыть может неправильно.. не получилось ничего(

Comment: `<Button Command={Binding..ваша команда} CommandParameter={Binding..ваш итем} >`

Comment: А во ViewModel как его использовать? он должен быть входящим параметром у события OnButtonClick?

Comment: Забудьте про события для кнопок. Вы пишете команду, которая что то делает с элементом из вашего списка. Команда принимает этот элемент на входе. Вы биндите эту команду к кнопке во вьюхе. Там же в эту команду ваш элемент биндите через параметр. В итоге юзер жмет кнопку, вьюха видит команду, вызывает это команду и передает элемент списка в неё как параметр

Comment: Прошу, напишите минимальский код, вьюхи и как обработать эту команду во ViewModel для общего понимания, буду крайне признателен

Comment: [тыц](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.4.php)

Comment: А что с метками? Тут и wpf и xamarin одновременно?

Comment: Только Xamarin, случайно вставил, сорь, исправил

Comment: Проблема пока не решена, разбираюсь с примером, который мне любезно посоветовал tym32167, как разберусь отпишусь, если кто то более простое пояснение даст в этом посте, буду благодарен)

Comment: XAML можете добавить в вопрос, а то немного не понятно про список итемов с кнопками.

Comment: @Emigrant  Emigrant Добрый вечер, проблему так и не поборол, изменил описание, и проверил работу команды при клике кнопку, во ViewModel передается событие клика, но если назначить команду на кнопку, которая будет находиться внутри ListView, то команда почему то не реагирует, вроде и BindingContext  прописал, но результата нет, помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы все заработало, Вам необходимо внести минимальные изменения.

В XAML:

В шаблоне ItemTemplate, чтобы биндинг команды был к ViewModel, необходимо указать Source, иначе биндинг будет к Вашей модели. В CommandParameter достаточно указать {Binding .}

Следовательно, заменить

```
<Button  Text="В корзину"  Command="{Binding AddDelCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
```

на

```
<Button  Text="В корзину"  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListViewKategor}, Path=BindingContext.AddDelCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```

Мой вариант.

Код XAML:

```
 <StackLayout Padding="5">
    <ListView x:Name="MyListViewKategor"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="White" >
                        <StackLayout WidthRequest="160" HeightRequest="120"  Padding="10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}"   />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout >
                            <Label  Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                            <Label Text="{Binding CountOneitem}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Rub}" />
                            <Button  Text="В корзину"  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListViewKategor}, Path=BindingContext.AddDelCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- тест стек находится под листвью -->
        <Label Text="{Binding Message}"/>
        <Button  Text="В корзину"  Command="{Binding AddDelCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class KorzinaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddDelCommand => new Command(OnAddDel);

    private string _message = "default text";
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            _message = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Message));
        }
    }

    public KorzinaViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item{ Name = "Item1", Rub=100.99 },
            new Item{ Name = "Item2", Rub=200.99 },
            new Item{ Name = "Item3", Rub=300.99 }
        };
    }

    private void OnAddDel(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Item item)
            Message = item.Name;
        else
            Message = "click";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Rub { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю тебя, добрый человек))
Изучаю еще только Xamarin и не было понимания, почему биндинг не работал на кнопке внутри ListView, еще раз спасибо!

Для тех кто не хочет погружаться, но интересует вопрос, как привязать команду к кнопке внутри ListView, то ответ кроется тута

<Button  Text="В корзину"  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListViewKategor}, Path=BindingContext.AddDelCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>